# How to check db2 version

Tags: sql, db2

How to check db2 version on Z/OS using only SQL commands?

Thanks,
Melita

Answer (score 66):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT service_level, fixpack_num FROM TABLE
  (sysproc.env_get_inst_info())
  as INSTANCEINFO
```

It works on LUW, so I can't guarantee that it'll work on z/OS, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Damn and blast. I wish things would work the same between the two.

Comment: Example of execution:`SELECT service_level, fixpack_num FROM TABLE(sysproc.env_get_inst_info()) as INSTANCEINFO `
`DB2 v11.1.4.4','4'`

Answer (score 23):

There is also the env_inst_info admin view. As with CanSpice I can only vouch for LUW, but there should at least be a similar view available for Z/OS.

```
SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.ENV_INST_INFO
```

Comment: For me, it is SYSIBMADM.ENV_SYS_INFO. Since I cannot find the table you provided, I just look at the tables under SYSIBMADM that looks like it. Thanks for this answer I found mine.

Answer (score 23):

```
SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Comment: This returns a value like 'DSN090100'. To see what that means checkout the link in [@Michael Sharek's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3825610/152061).

Comment: Link in answer referenced above currently redirects [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_refs2builtinsessionvars.htm). Adding for future reference, in case IBM deprecates the original link.

Comment: I have `SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "GETVARIABLE" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884` on this

Answer (score 11):

There is a typo in your SQL. Fixed version is below:

`SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;`

I ran this on the IBM Mainframe under Z/OS in QMF and got the following results.
We are currently running DB2 Version 8 and upgrading to Ver 10.

```
DSN08015  -- Format seems to be DSNVVMMM
-- PPP IS PRODUCT STRING 'DSN'
-- VV IS VERSION NUMBER E.G. 08
-- MMM IS MAINTENANCE LEVEL E.G. 015
```

Comment: I get, "Qualified object name SYSDUMMY1 not valid" on As/400

Answer (score 10):

I used

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.ENV_GET_INST_INFO());
```

from tyranitar and that worked on Z/OS. Here's what I got:

```
SERVICE_LEVEL
DB2 v9.7.0.6
```

I'd vote up if I could! Thanks!!

Comment: This will *not* work on z/OS.  You are running on DB2 for Linux, UNIX or Windows to get this result.

Comment: Works for me! I get:
 |INST_NAME|IS_INST_PARTITIONABLE|NUM_DBPARTITIONS|INST_PTR_SIZE|RELEASE_NUM|SERVICE_LEVEL|BLD_LEVEL|PTF|FIXPACK_NUM|NUM_MEMBERS
|xxx|0|1|64|060A010E|DB2 v10.5.0.9|s170908|IP24025|9|1

Comment: I confirm that this is not working on z/OS for me too.

Answer (score 8):

Both worked for me.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.ENV_GET_INST_INFO());
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.ENV_INST_INFO;
```

Comment: thanks, the first query gives SERVICE_LEVEL and RELEASE_NUM

Answer (score 7):

To find out the fixpak information using command prompt:
db2level

To find out the version and license information using command prompt:
db2licm -l

```
C:\Users\Administrator>db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "DB2")
uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10051" with level identifier
"0602010E".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.5.100.63", "s130816", "IP23521", and Fix Pack

"1".
Product is installed at "C:\SQLLIB" with DB2 Copy Name "DB2COPY1".


C:\Users\Administrator>db2licm -l
Product name:                     "IBM Data Server Client"
Product identifier:               "db2client"
Version information:              "10.5"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can query for the built-in session variables with SQL. To identify the version of DB2 on z/OS, you need the [SYSIBM.VERSION variable.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_refs2builtinsessionvars.html)
This will return the [PRDID - the product identifier](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/msgs/src/tpc/dsnl200i.html). You can look up the human-readable version in the [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/search/?scope=SSEPEK).

```
SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION')
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;

-- for example, the above returns DSN10015
-- DSN10015 identifies DB2 10 in new-function mode (see second link above)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the first or the second:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.ENV_GET_INST_INFO());
SELECT * FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.ENV_GET_PROD_INFO());
SELECT * FROM TABLE(SYSPROC.ENV_GET_SYS_INFO());
```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu though

Answer (score 2):

In z/OS while on version 10, use of `CURRENT APPLICATION COMPATIBILITY` is not allowed. You will have to resort to:

```
SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') AS VERSION,
       GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.NEWFUN')  AS COMPATIBILITY
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Here is a link to all the variables available: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_refs2builtinsessionvars.html#db2z_refs2builtinsessionvars

Answer (score 1):

Another one in v11:

```
select CURRENT APPLICATION COMPATIBILITY from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Result:

```
V11R1
```

It's not the current version, but the current configured level for the application.

Answer (score 0):

For `DB2`:

```
"SELECT * FROM SYSIBMADM.ENV_INST_INFO" - SERVICE_LEVEL
```

Answer (score 0):

In AIX you can try:

```
db2level
```

Example output:

```
db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable:
"db2inst1") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL09077" with level
identifier "08080107".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v9.7.0.7", "s121002", "IP23367", and Fix Pack
"7".
Product is installed at "/db2_09_07".
```

Answer (score 0):

db2ls command will display the db2level along with the install path and install date.

To determine the specific product installed:

```
db2ls -p -q -b <installpath>
```

on **db2ls** command.

The following will appear:

```
Install Path       Level   Fix Pack   Special Install Number   Install Date    Installer UID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/opt/ibm/db2/V9.7  9.7.0.7        7                      Thu Aug  1 12:25:53 2013 CDT     0
```

visit [IBM Website](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21667518)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT GETVARIABLE(('SYSIBM.VERSION')
 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
-- PPP IS PRODUCT STRING 'DSN'
-- VV IS VERSION NUMBER E.G., 10, 11
-- M IS MAINTENANCE LEVEL E.G. 5

-DISPLAY GROUP
 THIS WILL DISPLAY THE LEVEL CM, ENFM, N
```