# SQL to add an additional column that counts duplicate values for a particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, count, distinct

I'm seem to be having an off day and can't seem to get this query working.

Initially my query without the use of DISTINCT included the repetition of 2 rows:

```
STAT       SHNO      UPDD         UPDT       ORDERNO 
40       ASN123    20141022   150048       40303020
30       ASN124    20141022   150048       40303021
30       ASN124    20141022   150048       40303021
40       ASN123    20141022   150048       40303020
30       ASN125    20141022   150048       40303021
```

I changed the query to include DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
    STAT, SHNO, UPDD, UPDT, ORDERNO
FROM   
    BLUEWATER
```

and I now get the desired resultset:

```
STAT         SHNO         UPDD        UPDT      ORDERNO
30         SHN124       20141022      150048      40303021
30         SHN125       20141022      150048      40303021
40         SHN123       20141022      150048      40303020
```

However what I am trying to do is use COUNT to generate a column in my results that counts the rows where ORDERNO is not unique and wish to obtain the following:

```
STAT         SHNO         UPDD        UPDT      ORDERNO      ORDERNOCOUNT     
30         SHN124       20141022      150048    40303021      2                
30         SHN125       20141022      150048    40303021      2                
40         SHN123       20141022      150048    40303020      1
```

Comment: Please tag with the version of SQL Server you're using, so we don't have to guess. Also, the fact that you need `DISTINCT` in the first place is a clue that there is a fundamental problem with the underlying design. (Because of the cryptic column names - who named those? - it's largely impossible for us to guess at what the design problems might be.)

Comment: The names are cryptic to me also and I received a spreadsheet with description for only some of the columns although I won't need them all. I don't have client access and don't find it practical to always connect via VPN so I recreated the DB2 table in SQL Server R2. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use group by and COUNT() OVER ... what version are you using?

```
SELECT STAT, SHNO, UPDD, UPDT, ORDERNO, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ORDERNO) AS ORDERNOCOUNT
FROM BLUEWATER     
GROUP BY STAT, SHNO, UPDD, UPDT, ORDERNO
```

as sub-select

```
SELECT gsub.STAT, gsub.SHNO, gsub.UPDD, gsub.UPDT, gsub.ORDERNO, sub.c AS ORDERNOCOUNT
FROM 
(
   SELECT STAT, SHNO, UPDD, UPDT, ORDERNO
   FROM BLUEWATER
   GROUP BY STAT, SHNO, UPDD, UPDT, ORDERNO
) gsub
JOIN (
   SELECT ORDERNO, COUNT(*) as c
   FROM BLUEWATER
   GROUP BY ORDERNO
) as sub ON gsub.ORDERNO = sub.ORDERNO
```

Comment: Well you would get 1 instead of 2 for the first two results, because `SHNO` changes...

Comment: Seems more appropriate to use `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ORDERNO)` but, since the OP failed to bother to mention what version they're using...

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. I am using SQL Server 2008, version 10.50.1617 but I will be porting the queries to DB2 running on the iseries AS400

Comment: @TobyDerrum: v10.50 is SQL Server **2008 R2** (which is **not** the same as **2008** ....)

Comment: @TobyDerrum -- DB2 has many versions too.  But if you are using 9.7 or after you should be fine.  It will support COUNT...OVER

Comment: Unfortunately it gave me the following on DB2: `java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0104] Token ( was not valid. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO.`

Comment: @TobyDerrum - What version of DB2 do you have?

Comment: I dont know. I doubt they'd risk upgrading so I'm guessing fairly old.  I ran every command I found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821795/how-to-check-db2-version but got nothing back. Best I can do is ask tomorrow.

Comment: @TobyDerrum - I wrote a version that uses a sub-select above -- I didn't test it so it might have a typo -- but should get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated ! I tried this version on both DBs and keep getting `java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0203] Name ORDERNO is ambiguous.`

Comment: @TobyDerrum - ok... put `sub` or `BLUEWATER` in front of `ORDERNO` on the select and group by line

Comment: @Hogan I get `java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0122] Column C or expression in SELECT list not valid.`. There is no error when I add sub.C to the last GROUP BY line but it gives me a wrong count for ORDERNOCOUNT

Comment: @TobyDerrum - ok I gave it another shot.  I've been spoiled by the windowing functions.

Comment: @Hogan I appreciate your efforts. It is still calculating the ORDERNOCOUNT from the total ORDERNO count in the table not those on display.

Comment: @TobyDerrum - Yes that is what you wanted -- a count of the number of orders with that ordernumber.  If you want something else you will have to explain what it is.