# DB2 concatenate unique column values into one row, comma seperated

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Two tables:

```
Parts Table:
Part_Number   Load_Date   TQTY
m-123         19940102    32
1234Cf        20010809    3
wf9-2         20160421    14


Locations Table:
PartNo     Condition     Location   QTY
m-123      U             A02        2
1234Cf     S             A02        3
m-123      U             B01        1
wf9-2      S             A06        7
m-123      S             A18        29
wf9-2      U             F16        7

Result:
Part_Number   Load_Date  TQTY   U_LOC    UQTY    S_LOC   SQTY
m-123         19940102   32     A02,B01  3       A18     29
1234Cf        20010809   3                       A02     3
wf9-2         20160421   14     F16      7       A06     7
```

I am having trouble finding a solution to this with my current DB2 version. I am not completely sure how to find the version, but it is running on an AS400 system, and it seems the version of DB2, is tied to the OS version. Which the box is using: **Operating system: i5/OS Version: V5R4M0**
(I tried some commands to get the DB2 version using these suggestions [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821795/how-to-check-db2-version) but none of them worked, like most stated).

In regards to concatenating multiple rows of column data into one row I have come across many articles stating to use **XMLAGG** or **xmlserialize**, [Here](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/7720.xmlagg) and, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188542/db2-comma-separated-output) but I get an error stating the command is not recognized.

Not sure where to go from here, as there seem to be solutions, but I can't get those already suggested functions to work.

---

**EDIT:**
Using the accepted answer and explanation, as well as the example 
[HERE](https://academy.vertabelo.com/blog/get-to-know-the-power-of-sql-recursive-queries/) to get a basic idea of recursion with a simple example, and it was
[HERE](http://radheshk.blogspot.com/2008/02/sql-tips-techniques-string-aggregation.html) using the "`SELECT rownumber() over(partition by category)`" statements that really helped pull it all together. Once I understood that statement of course.

I also learned to make sure the data used in the recursion is as narrowed down as possible and then joined up with extra data later. This makes for exponentially faster results. <-- This seems pretty obvious, but when trying to figure all of this out, it wasn't obvious and my query was pretty slow. Once I understood what was actually happening better it was easier to make adjustments for really fast results.

Comment: XMLAGG?? The function you want is LISTAGG (http://www.ibmmainframeforum.com/db2/topic10923.html) XMLAGG is for creating XML.  *not what you want to do*

Comment: LISTAGG is for V7R3, and XML functions such as xmlserialize are for V7R1.  With V5R4, you have to make a stored procedure to do that in SQL

Comment: @Dam, can you provide an example or something to get me started? We are migrating from AS400 to ASP.NET MVC technology, and for the time being using DB2 to keep the old and new programs in sync. So I am not too experienced with DB2 language, other than universal statements.  I may resort to handling this with data structures in C#, but want to avoid overhead if I can.

Comment: I did come across this article: vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/group-concat But I am trying to figure out how to work through it. It's a little beyond my skill level of DB2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather complicated, so I will show all my work:

Table definitions

```
create table parts
  (part_number      Varchar(64),
   load_date        Date,
   total_qty        Dec(5,0));
create table locations
  (part_number      Varchar(64),
   condition        Char(1),
   location         Char(3),
   qty              Dec(5,0));
insert into parts
  values ('m-123',  '1994-01-02', 32),
         ('1234Cf', '2001-08-09',  3),
         ('wf9-2',  '2016-04-21', 14);
insert into locations
  values ('m-123',  'U', 'A02', 2),
         ('1234Cf', 'S', 'A02', 3),
         ('m-123',  'U', 'B01', 1),
         ('wf9-2',  'S', 'A06', 7),
         ('m-123',  'S', 'A18', 29),
         ('wf9-2',  'U', 'F16', 7);
```

The query:

```
with -- CTE's
  -- This collects locations into a comma seperated list
  tmp (part_number, condition, location, csv, level) as (
    select part_number, condition, min(location), 
           cast(min(location) as varchar(128)), 1
      from locations
      group by part_number, condition
    union all
    select a.part_number, a.condition, b.location, 
           a.csv || ',' || b.location, a.level + 1
      from tmp a
        join locations b using (part_number, condition)
      where a.csv not like '%' || b.location || '%'
        and b.location > a.location),
  -- This chooses the correct csv list, and adds quantity for the condition
  tmp2 (part_number, condition, csv, qty) as (    
    select t.part_number, t.condition, t.csv, 
           (select sum(qty) qty
              from locations 
              where part_number = t.part_number
                and condition = t.condition)
      from tmp t
      where level = (select max(level)
              from tmp 
              where part_number = t.part_number
                and condition = t.condition))
-- This is the final select that combines the parts file with
-- the second stage CTE and arranges things horizontally by condition
select p.part_number, p.load_date, 
       (select sum(qty) 
          from locations 
          where part_number = p.part_number) as total_qty, 
       coalesce(u.csv, '') as u_loc,
       coalesce(u.qty, 0) as uqty,
       coalesce(s.csv, '') as s_loc, 
       coalesce(s.qty, 0) as sqty
  from parts p
    left outer join tmp2 u
      on u.part_number = p.part_number and u.condition = 'U'
    left outer join tmp2 s
      on s.part_number = p.part_number and s.condition = 'S'
  order by p.load_date;
```

---

**EDIT** I have had to add some extra bits in here to support more than two locations for a part/condition, and I have made the column naming in the CTEs more consistent. Ok, so let me explain this a bit, there are 3 parts to this quety, 2 CTEs and the query, you can see the three parts are separated by comments. The first CTE is a recursive CTE. It's purpose is to produce the comma separated location list. You should be able to run the select by itself to see just what it does. `tmp` is the table name, part_number, condition, csv, and level are the column names. A recursive CTE needs a `SELECT` to prime the CTE and a `UNION ALL` with a `SELECT` that fills in the next details. In this case the priming `SELECT` retrieves a part number, a condition, and the first location (alphabetically) for that combination. level is set to 1. If you run just the priming select, you will get:

```
part_number  condition  location  csv  level
-----------  ---------  --------  ---  -----
1234Cf          S       A01       A02    1
m-123           S       A18       A18    1
m-123           U       A02       A02    1
wf9-2           U       F16       F16    1
wf9-2           S       A06       A06    1
```

Note one line per part/condition. The remainder of the recursive CTE will fill in the remaining locations in `csv`, but it will actually add additional records so we need to filter the results here and later. So records are processed as they are added. The first rows listed above are joined with the location file
on part_number and condition. Note in the priming select I have a cast of the second `min(location)` to a `varchar(128)`. This leaves room for the `CSV` column to expand. Without this, it will still expand, but not enough to hold more than 2 locations.

The second select in the recursive CTE concatenates a comma and the next location to the end of `CSV`. The specific bit that does this is `a.csv || ',' || b.location`. It also increments the level column. This helps us keep track of where we are in the query. Eventually, the row with the highest `level` is the one we want to use. We also have a way to end the recursion, and some filters to reduce the number of rows added to the temporary result set. If we have 2 locations, `A02` and `B02`, left unchecked, we will get the following rows: `A02`, `A02,A02`, `A02,B02`, `A02,A02,A02`, `A02,B02,A02`, `A02,A02,B02`, `A02,B02,B02`, ... ad infinitum. The anti-duplication filter `where a.csv not like '%' || b.location || '%'` is sufficient for two locations to end the recursion, and minimize rows, like above, for locations `A02` and `B02`, with the anti-duplication filter, we will get rows `A02`, and `A02,B02`. Note that none of the other results from the first example with duplicate locations are returned. Adding a third location `C02` will yield, with anti-duplication filter, the following rows: `A02`, `A02,B02`, `A02,C02`, `A02,B02,C02`, `A02,C02,B02`. No duplicates here, but we do have redundant rows, and as you add locations, it gets worse. This is where we need a way to detect these redundant rows. Since we are starting with the lowest location number, we can always make sure that locations added to `CSV` are greater than the previously added location. To do that all we need to do is include a column in the result set that indicates which column was added (we could interrogate `CSV`, but that is harder). This is why we need the `location` column in `tmp`. Then we can write filter `b.location > a.location`. In the above 3 location example, this filter prevents row `A02,C02,B02` leaving just a single row with all three locations. Adding more than three locations to the locations file will cause the number of rows to expand even more in `TMP`, but for each part and condition, there will only be one row with all locations, and it will contain all locations in ascending order.

The second CTE does two things. First, it filters `TMP` to drop all but the rows containing all locations for a given part/condition. Second, it accumulates the total quantity for each part/condition.

The bit that performs the filtering is in the `where` clause:

```
where level = (select max(level)
        from tmp 
        where part_number = t.part_number
          and condition = t.condition))
```

Pretty straight forward. The bit that accumulates the total quantity for a part/condition is also an easy to understand sub-query:

```
(select sum(qty) qty
   from locations 
   where part_number = t.part_number
     and condition = t.condition)
```

The final piece of this monster query is the main select. It joins the parts file with the results of the second CTE to form the ultimate result set:

```
select p.part_number, p.load_date, 
       (select sum(qty) from locations where part_number = p.part_number) as total_qty,
       coalesce(u.csv, '') as u_loc, coalesce(u.qty, 0) as uqty,
       coalesce(s.csv, '') as s_loc, coalesce(s.qty, 0) as sqty
  from parts p
    left outer join tmp2 u
      on u.part_number = p.part_number and u.condition = 'U'
    left outer join tmp2 s
      on s.part_number = p.part_number and s.condition = 'S'
  order by p.load_date
```

Bits of note are the subquery to retrieve the total quantity from the `locations` table. You could use the `tqty` field in `parts`, but that can get out of sync with the actual quantities in the `locations` table. In addition there are two left outer joins with `tmp2`, one for condition `U`, and another for condition `S`. These construct the horizontal array of Location/Quantity in the result row. The last thing is the `coalesce` functions. These give null values (when a result from an outer join is missing) a default value.

**End of EDIT**

---

The final result is:

```
part_number  load_date   tqty  u_loc    uqty  s_loc  sqty
-----------  ----------  ----  -------  ----  -----  ----
m-123        1994-01-02   32   A02,B01    3   A18     29
1234Cf       2001-08-09    3              0   A02      3
wf9-2        2016-04-21   14   F16        7   A06      7
```

**Note** `XMLAGG` and `XMLSERIALIZE` became available at DB2 for i v7.1 and `LISTAGG` became available at DB2 for i v7.2. Most recent version as of 8/9/2017 is v7.3. As you are on v5r4, it is likely you will need not only a software, but also a hardware upgrade to get current.

Comment: Thank you for your in depth response. And for the Note. We are phasing out the box, after the conversion of applications, that's why I assume, it has an older version still. 

What is meant by, "CSV" and "LEVEL"  in the Query? I am not sure what that is connected to.

Comment: They are just field names I need later on in the query. CSV is the comma seperated list of concatenated locations. Level is just the number of locations that have been added to the list. I use level to choose which list to use for a given part/condition as there will be a list with 1 loc, a list with 2 locs, and 3, and 4 right up until you get all the locations in the list.

Comment: hmm, I copied your statement and only prepended the library to the table names, and I am getting a few errors after, "...union all select a.part_number,.. (here is where it stops) and throws, "SQL0255: Function not supported for query. Reason code 5.

Code 5 = A recursive common table expression is not supported for this query.

Comment: Hmmm... recursive CTE's became available at v5r4, but may have had some limitations. The above is working at v7.1, can't test at v5.4 since I don't have a system to test on.

Comment: I wrote a small recursive CTE for a sample, and it worked. So It's just being picky about something. I haven't used Recursion in SQL before.  So I am trying to understand your example and rewrite it myself. Can you explain more on how the first CTE is calling itself to store comma separated values into the CSV column(what is happening)? Also, what is the difference between defining column names in CTE tmp, vs not in CTE tmp2? Trying to wrap my head around this stuff for the first time. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I was hung up on a few key concepts that you cleared up which makes sense now (the reason for the count) and also, how "a.csv || ',' || b.location" is working. It wasn't clear to me how it was being stored into a.csv but I kind of caught on after looking over it enough times that (hopefully I am right) it's the way the CTE parameters are declared and the, "a.csv || ',' || b.location" is a value that gets stored into it. I was thinking somehow how that line kept += itself into a.csv. I think I got a good enough grasp on it now.

Comment: What really helped was walking through each query too (along with your detailed explanations) and outputting the data and just trying to walk through what was going on visually as well not just syntax wise.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

No idea what the rules are for UQTY, S_LOC, SQTY but here is the column you asked about ---

```
SELECT 
  P.Part_Number,
  P.Load_Date,
  P.TQTY,
  LISTAGG(L.Location, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY L.Location) AS U_LOC    
FROM "Parts Table" AS P
LEFT JOIN "Locations Table" AS L ON P.Part_Number = L.Part_Number
GROUP BY P.Part_Number, P.Load_Date, P.TQTY
```

Comment: Error Source: IBMDA400 Command
Error message: SQL0199: Keyword GROUP not expected.

Comment: As per Dam's comment above, it looks like the LISTAGG function is not available to me with my version.