# Generate Unique ID On a Select in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a select that look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTICT COL1, COL2, COL3
               FROM view a WHERE conditions ....
              ) QUERY
WHERE CONDITIONS... LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

I'm executing this from java and I need this query return an unique id.
So i try:

```
SELECT TRIM(CHAR(HEX(GENERATE_UNIQUE()))) AS GUID, QUERY.* FROM (SELECT DISTICT COL1, COL2, COL3
               FROM view a WHERE conditions ....
              ) QUERY
WHERE CONDITIONS... LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

This one return an error telling me I can't use this function in that place.
If i try:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(CHAR(HEX(GENERATE_UNIQUE()))) AS GUID, COL1, COL2, COL3
               FROM view a WHERE conditions ....
              ) QUERY
WHERE CONDITIONS... LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

I have duplicated rows because it is like I execute query wihout DISTINCT

Does anyone know a way to do it?

I don't know DB2 version (I have tried all solutions from [How to check db2 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821795/how-to-check-db2-version) )

Comment: Does the id have to be a GUID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a numeric `id` would do, how about just using `row_number()`:

```
SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COL1, COL2, COL3) as VARCHAR(255)) as unique_id,
       QUERY.*
FROM (SELECT DISTICT COL1, COL2, COL3
      FROM view a
      WHERE conditions ....
     ) QUERY
WHERE CONDITIONS...
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: My feeling is that the OP wants to generate a UUID or something similar which can never be duplicated (in theory).

Comment: I get an error from java Exception [EclipseLink-6044] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The primary key read from the row [ArrayRecord(
  => 1 ... ) I'm going to take a look to this error. But thank you very much.

Comment: Finally it works, I also have some problems with java ContructorResult. thank you

Comment: For future readers, check out this UUID generation answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62350083/db2-generate-guid-uuid).