# DB2 Generate GUID/UUID

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Is it possible to generate to GUID/UUID string in DB2 whose contents need to be absolutely unique in the universe? similar to uniqueidentifier data type in SQL server. In DB2 we got GENERATE_UNIQUE function, that ensures uniqueness **only** across multiple execution of the same function. I think i can try Java Routines in DB2. In worst possible case I can generate GUID/UUID from my Java app and send it across to DB2.. are there any other alternatives to achieve the same within DB2 without using external components/routines. Please suggest.

Thank you..

Comment: This is a FAQ. Do your research. Be sure to carefully analyze your motivation for UUID , and especially how they will be used in the phyical model if your database uses tables with distribute-by-hash.  Assume:Nothing.

Comment: @mao When you refer to a FAQ, you should at least put a link to that FAQ. It would be even better to quote the FAQ in an answer. That way, it becomes helpful to everybody.

Answer (score 6):

Try This...

```
   SELECT  LEFT(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdef123456789', '1234567890' ),8) CONCAT '-' CONCAT LEFT(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdef123456789', '1234567890' ),4) CONCAT '-' CONCAT LEFT(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdef123456789', '1234567890' ),4) CONCAT '-' CONCAT LEFT(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdef123456789', '1234567890' ),4) CONCAT '-' CONCAT LEFT(TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000000 )), 'abcdef123456789', '1234567890' ),12)  FROM YOURTABLE
```

Comment: brilliant, you saved me a lot of time with that!

Comment: The generated GUID will never contain digit 56789 because of how translate works. It will only translate the first 10 characters because that is all of the characters in the 3rd parameter '1234567890'

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without external function in Db2.
A Java UDF is the simplest way for this.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, here is how to generate a UUID version 1 (time-based). Several caveats apply:

- There is always a possibility of generating duplicate UUIDs
- The RAND() function is not as random as we think
- The third quad part of the UUID could use a SEQUENCE object instead of RAND()
- The "B" part of the UUID is supposed to come from the MAC address of the system, it should be used as a unique instance ID instead of RAND().
- 

```
-- vvvvvvvv-uuuu-1ttt-ssss-mmmmmmmmmmmm
-- 1                 4 bit version
-- tttuuuuvvvvvvvv   60 bit timestamp
-- ssss              2 bit variant and 14 bit sequence from 8000-BFFF
-- mmmmmmmmmmmm      48 bit mac address
WITH UUIDMAKE(A,B) AS (
SELECT 
RIGHT(HEX(864000000000*BIGINT(DAYS(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE)-577736)
+10000000*BIGINT(MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE))
+BIGINT(10*MICROSECOND(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE)+10*RAND())),15)
,
'02'||RIGHT(HEX(RAND()),10)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)
SELECT 
SUBSTR(A,8,8)
||'-' || SUBSTR(A,4,4)
||'-1'|| SUBSTR(A,1,3) 
||'-' || RIGHT(HEX(INT(32768+RAND()*16384)),4)
||'-' || B
FROM UUIDMAKE
```